# Power BI Dax Multiple IF AND Statements

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a DAX query in Power BI - see below.
I have created a new column in the data and I want to Group `AgeWhenFirstSold(Mo)` into Age buckets.

The result I get from this query is 0-5 Months but the 6-11 Months doesn't show in the column

```
Group AgeWhenFirstSold(Mo)- 6 Months =
IF (
    AND ( Sheet1[AgeWhenFirstSold(Mo)] >= "0", Sheet1[AgeWhenFirstSold(Mo)] <= "5" ),
    "0 - 5 Months",
    IF (
        AND ( Sheet1[AgeWhenFirstSold(Mo)] > "5", Sheet1[AgeWhenFirstSold(Mo)] <= "11" ),
        "6 - 11 Months"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your issue is that alphabetically "11" <= "5"

Try using `VALUE(<text>)`
"Converts a text string that represents a number to a number."

e.g. `VALUE( Sheet1[AgeWhenFirstSold(Mo)] ) >= 0`

**However you can also configure bins and groups to avoid having to extract them with DAX:**

Right-click AgeWhenFirstSold(Mo) in the FIELDS section of Power BI Desktop and choose New Group:

[image]

A dialog then allows you to configure your new group.

An example:

[image]

Comment: What I mean by Group is "Bucket" ie. when AgeWhenFirstSold(Mo)>="0" and AgeWhenFirstSold(Mo)<="5" and call this "0-5 Months",and have it blank it these conditions are not met.But my 2nd set of conditions 

IF( AND (Sheet1[AgeWhenFirstSold(Mo)]>"5",Sheet1[AgeWhenFirstSold(Mo)]<="11"), "6-11 Months does not show up in the results

Comment: It does bins. I think your issue may be that you've got strings instead of numbers for your ages? Try changing them to integers. But with strings you can add multiple values into multiple groups/buckets in that dialog.

Comment: I've added an example screenshot of dropping multiple different string values into multiple different groups

Comment: I suspect your issue is that alphabetically "11" <= "5". I've updated my answer.